# Logging in to the Area 51 Discussion Zone will successfully log you into the main Area 51 site, but not the Discussion Zone itself

Tags: bug, status-deferred, area-51, authentication

In the Area 51 Discussion Zone (DZ), the log in link is for area51.stackexchange.com, not area51.meta.stackexchange.com.

Because of domain restrictions, etc., after successfully logging in you get redirected back to the Discussion Zone, and although you are logged into the main Area 51 site, you aren't logged into the DZ. If you come to meta.stackexchange.com then you can log in and the single sign in will carry across to the DZ.

Comment: When you click on the log in link from the DZ it will log you into area51 but not the DZ. I would've thought it would work as they're all on stackexchange.com, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, it's an unfortunate side-effect of how universal login and Area 51 work. Even more unfortunately, it's been this way for the past 3-ish years and it's not likely to get addressed any time soon.

Comment: @AdamLear Wouldn't it be enough to change the link to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2farea51.meta.stackexchange.com%2f It wouldn't look as good with the site header changing completely, but at least you would actually be logged in after completing the log in process.