# Cannot authenticate to area51 whereas area51.meta works

Tags: support, bug

I've already posted this on area51 meta but as it <s>is a tumbleweed question over there</s> doesn't get a lot of traction, [deleted there](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28079/cannot-authenticate-to-area51-whereas-area51-meta-works) (link only works for 10K+ users) and posting here instead (and probably be downvoted back into the stone age).

OK, so I'm a total security and privacy <s>nazi</s> nerd, so I actively refuse all cookies everywhere except for the sites I visit more than once/week.

So https://stackexchange.com is allowed to store session cookies only as are all the other sites in the SE network which I regularly visit like Ask Ubuntu, Super User, Server Fault, Stack Overflow, sstatic.net etc and it works nicely.

For some or other reason, if I authenticate on area51 I can see some kind of avatar when I'm on https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com:

[image: Meta avatar]

And I was able to post and subsequently edit this question over there...

## but

(and that's a big but)  if I go to the main area51 site (https://area51.stackexchange.com/), it looks like I never logged on:

[image: Main site avatar]

And if I try to log in, it won't let me! *What am I missing here?*

#### Additional info:

Just noticed that surfing to https://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com

gives the following output under FireFox:

```
discuss.area51.stackexchange.com uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is only valid for the following names: 

*.stackexchange.com,
stackoverflow.com, *.stackoverflow.com, stackauth.com, sstatic.net, 
*.sstatic.net, serverfault.com, *.serverfault.com, superuser.com, 
*.superuser.com, stackapps.com, openid.stackauth.com, stackexchange.com, 
*.meta.stackexchange.com, meta.stackexchange.com, mathoverflow.net, 
*.mathoverflow.net, askubuntu.com, *.askubuntu.com, stacksnippets.net, 
*.blogoverflow.com, blogoverflow.com, *.meta.stackoverflow.com, 
*.stackoverflow.email, stackoverflow.email, stackoverflow.blog 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

Correlation, causation or not related?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311593/256282

Comment: Urgh!  Thanks!  It's not me! **;-)** @curiousdannii But it doesn't look like it'll be addressed soon...

Comment: They're related, but if I've understood what you've written here, yours is the reverse problem.

Comment: Yeah, but it answers my question and hopefully it'll answer someone else's too and maybe the powers that be will do something about it.